# WPF Page.Unloaded called after sub has run

Tags: wpf, vb.net

In this scenario when a user changes access to a different business (multi business accounting) it runs through a sub that closes all open tabs and changes the status of any that are still held open in editing mode.

Everything runs really well, the tabs are closed and then the ID for the new business is loaded.

The trouble is the Page.Unloaded event is running after the entire sub has run and is therefore updating the incorrect DB if any pages were left open in the edit mode.

Is there any way to force any pages that were closed as part of the sub to run unloaded before completing the rest of the code?

Thanks

Edit re comment from  Pragmateek

This is an exampled of the unloaded event

```
Private Sub Website_WebPage_Page_Unloaded(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Unloaded
    Try
        Dim SaveUpdateButton As Button = Website_WebPage_Grid.FindName("WebsiteWebPage_SaveUpdateButton")
        Dim vScrollViewer As ScrollViewer = Website_WebPage_Grid.FindName("WebsiteWebPage_ScrollViewer")
        If NewRecord = True Then
            RemoveHandler SaveUpdateButton.Click, AddressOf Website_WebPage_DB_Insert

        Else
            'Edited record
            Dim EditButton As Button = Website_WebPage_Grid.FindName("WebsiteWebPage_EditButton")
            Dim EditWebPageButton As Button = Website_WebPage_Grid.FindName("Website_WebPage_EditWebPageButton")
            RemoveHandler EditButton.Click, AddressOf Website_WebPage_ToggleEditMode_Click
            RemoveHandler vScrollViewer.MouseDoubleClick, AddressOf Website_WebPage_ToggleEditMode_Click
            RemoveHandler Me.MouseDown, AddressOf Website_WebPage_MouseDown
            RemoveHandler SaveUpdateButton.Click, AddressOf Website_WebPage_DB_Update
            RemoveHandler EditWebPageButton.Click, AddressOf WebsiteWebPage_BrowseToClick
        End If

        If OpenForEdit = True Then
            If DB_Functions_ReleaseDT("HOA3_Pages", Page_ID, "Page_ID") = False Then
                EditForm_Error()
            Else
                OpenForEdit = False
            End If
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        EmailError(ex)
    End Try
End Sub
```

If the tab was left in edit mode OpenForEdit will be true and it will call DB_Functions_ReleaseDT

```
Public Function DB_Functions_ReleaseDT(ByVal TableName As String, ByVal FileID As Integer, ByVal PKey As String) As Boolean
    Try
        UpdateOpenForEdit(False, TableName)
        vService = New Service1Client
        strSQL = "UPDATE " & TableName & " SET Open_Editing = 0, Editing_Name = 'System' WHERE " & PKey & " = " & FileID
        If vService.InsertDataHOA(strSQL, "3 DB_Functions 43", Current_HOA_ID) = False Then
            Return False
        Else
            Return True
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        EmailError(ex)
        Return False
    Finally
        If Not vService Is Nothing Then
            vService.Close()
            vService = Nothing
        End If
    End Try

End Function
```

The problem is Unloaded is running far too late and the variable Current_HOA_ID has changed

Comment: Each page should keep a copy of, or reference to, the DB and the data it is working on.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out the answer was quite simple - the sub was being run twice, so adding...

```
e.Handled = True
```

.. as the first line of code sorted the problem out